# How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height with gap?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I'm using Bootstrap. How can I make three columns all the same height including the gap?
Here is the screenshot;
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onbVP.png)

Here is the code;

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 service mt-4">
      <div class="p-3">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-laptop-code fs-1"></i>
        </div>
        <h5 class="mb-4 mt-2">Web Development</h5>
        <p>I provide full Web Development according to your needs.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 service mt-4">
      <div class="p-3">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-palette fs-1"></i>
        </div>
        <h5 class="mb-4 mt-2">Web Design</h5>
        <p>I will do the best and most Modern Web App Designs for your website.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-xl-4 service mt-4">
      <div class="p-3">
        <div class="icon">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-mobile-screen-button fs-1"></i>
        </div>
        <h5 class="mb-4 mt-2">Responsive Design</h5>
        <p>Fully Responsive Design using Bootstrap or Media Queries.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is some CSS;

```
.p-3{
  text-align: center;
  background: #202020;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `height: 100%` to class `p-3` will solve the problem.

Edit the CSS like the following;

```
.p-3{
  height: 100%;       //add this to the CSS code
  text-align: center;
  background: #202020;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<div id="myContainer" class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4" id="myItem">
            <div id= "myCard">
                this is my item
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="myItem">
            <div id= "myCard">
                this is my item
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="myItem">
            <div id= "myCard">
                this is my item
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
#myContainer{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#myItem{
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#myCard{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    background-color: blue;
    height:300px;
    width:95%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.row>div {
  display: grid;
}
```